# jQuery change multiple attributes or replace entire html

Tags: jquery, optimization

I was wondering if it were more efficient/faster to change multiple attributes with jQuery or to just change replace all the html in one go. This is the code i am using at the moment.

```
// shows the table and changes the image to up
showTable = function(tableId){
    $('#img' + tableId).attr("src", images["up"]).attr("alt", "Hide Table").attr("title", "Hide Table");
    $('#' + tableId).fadeIn(250);
}
```

or would this be faster?

```
// shows the table and changes the image to up
showTable = function(tableId){
    $('#img' + tableId).replaceWith('some html');
    $('#' + tableId).fadeIn(250);
}
```

Comment: Just test it, you have the code. Which way was faster? If you cannot tell a difference then it doesn't matter. "... premature optimization is the root of all evil" - Donald Knuth.

Comment: @lashleigh I have finished the web application and am doing refactoring and such. I asked cause I am new to all this, so I don't really know how to test javascript effeciency. And I don't know everything so I seek the wisdom of those around me. I didn't know i could do something like what yan.kun does. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
$('#greatphoto').attr({
  alt: 'Beijing Brush Seller',
  title: 'photo by Kelly Clark'
});
```

Example taken from [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Answer (score 6):

Given that you're taking a quarter of a second to fade in the result and this isn't a tight loop, you're not going to notice any performance difference between the two. As yan.kun points out, you can make the code a bit more concise by using the multi-set (map) version of [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2), but with three attributes not in a tight loop, it's not going to make a *speed* difference. (If it were, I'd avoid calling `attr` entirely and use the element's own reflected properties — [`src`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-97320704), [`alt`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-92701314), and [`title`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-78276800) are all reflected.)

Having said that, there are *other* reasons to update elements rather than replace them. For instance, if you have any handlers attached to the elements, if you update the elements' attributes, the handlers remain attached; if you *replace* the elements, the handlers aren't attached (because they were attached to the old ones). Replacing elements also causes reflow, which can be significant (or not) depending on your DOM structure.

Comment: +1 for the explanation, and the pitfalls of replacing elements.